# Editing .htaccess for multiple parameters and pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am struggling to understand how to edit my .htaccess file.

Currently i have the following url `example.com/fixture.php?country=UK&cup=prem&year=1998&id=123`

I would like to achieve `example.com/UK/prem/1998/123`

On each of the parameters in the URL will have a page for example `example.com/UK/prem/` will have info regarding the league and other cups same as the country parameter will have info on the page too.

Currently here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^fixture\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /fixture.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ /fixture.php?country=$1&cup=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /fixture.php?country=$1&cup=$2year=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Currently I only get a 404 status. I have searched stack overflow and adapted the above code, this is where I think I run into issues....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following rules set in htaccess file. Please make sure your htaccess file is present in root folder/directory.

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
##Blocking direct access to fixture.php here, added NC flag here.
RewriteRule ^fixture\.php$ - [NC,L]

##Rules for handling 4 parameters in uri.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/(\d{4})/\d{3}/?$ /fixture.php?country=$1&cup=$2year=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA]  

##Rules for handling 2 parameters in uri.    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/([^/]+)/?$ /fixture.php?country=$1&cup=$2 [L,QSA]

##Rules for handling 1 parameter in uri.
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ /fixture.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: If your url is always having UK as first part then you can change 2nd rule to `RewriteRule ^(UK)/([^/]*)/(\d{4})/\d{3}/?$ /fixture.php?country=$1&cup=$2year=$3&id=$4 [L,QSA] ` too in above Rules.